# LESS extend() not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to write a class 'selected' for my app's buttons. 
When a button hasClass 'selected' its look and feel should be the same as Bootstrap's 'btn-primary'.

Bootstrap css defines (for example):

```
.btn-primary { background-color:#00F; color:#FFF; }
```

I wrote my class as follows:

```
button.selected:extend(.btn-primary) {};
```

1) Is it supposed to work like that?

2) If 1) is yes, then my css is not working. The selected class does not inherit color and background-color from btn-primary.

**UPDATE**

Some of my markup:

```
<div class="filters">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg type">
            <button type="button" class="btn selected" data-filter="all">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
                All
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-filter="positive">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
                In
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-filter="negative">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
                Out
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my LESS:

```
.filters {
            .type {
                button.selected:extend(.btn-primary) {};
            }
        }
```

My main less file:

```
@import '../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

@import "utils.less";
@import "flex.less";
@import "index.less";
@import "transactions.less";
```

Obviously, if I give the button the class .btn-primary in markup... it simply works.

Comment: Yes, it should work and compile successfully. Can you create a sample demo to see where you are going wrong? CodePen, CSSDeck etc would allow you to create a demo with Less code.

Comment: updated with snippets of real code

Comment: Is the code for the `.btn-primary` also in the same Less file (or) are you importing a bootstrap less file? Can you please show how you are including if you are using an external file.

Comment: I am importing the bootstrap compiled css, see update

Comment: I don't think that you can extend from the CSS file. You should probably try to import the `bootstrap.less` file from the `less` folder. Note with v1.5.0 of Less, you could also use the `(reference)` directive to avoid getting all bootstrap classes in your resultant file.

Comment: I imported bootstrap.less and it worked. Sorry and thank you very much! Add it as answer

Comment: Actually just now managed to find out that you can extend `.css` files  but that should be done with the `(less)` directive in the import statement. I will add both in the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When we simply import a CSS file with the `.css` extension it will be treated as CSS and the `@import` statement left as-is.

For the `extend` feature to work, Less compiler has to interpret the imported file as a Less file. This can be done in two ways and they are as follows:

**Option 1:** (Using the [`(reference)`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) directive)

Using the `(reference)` directive, allows for pulling in only the targeted/referenced styles from the external bootstrap library. Hence, it would result in a smaller file and is preferred when you are going to reference only few styles from a large library (like bootstrap). Note that this directive was introduced only with Less v1.5.0 and hence will not work in lower compiler versions.

```
@import (reference) 'less/bootstrap.less';

.filters {
    .type {
        button.selected:extend(.btn-success) {};
    }
}
```

---

**Option 2:** (Using the [`(less)`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-less) directive)

When the `(less)` directive is used, the Less compiler would treat the code present within the imported file as Less code (irrespective of the file extension) and hence would allow extending any rule-sets/classes specified within it. However, the drawback of using this directive is that the entire contents of the `.css` file (including classes that you may not require in the output file) will be copied to the output. This was introduced in Less v1.4.0.

```
@import (less) 'bootstrap.css';

.filters {
    .type {
        button.selected:extend(.btn-success) {};
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also combine both to reference a file and treat it as a less file `@import (reference, less) '../sass/compiled/bootstrap.css';`