# How can I use Bootstrap in LESS without having to include it in the actual file?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

So my problem is that I want to include bootstrap in my project, but I don't wanna have to regenerate all the CSS files on the fly.

Here's what I want to achieve:

1. Include the complete finished CSS/JS files for Bootstrap as I would usually
2. Create classes that extend Bootstrap's with other LESS files. For example:

   ```
   .my-column {
       .col-sm-6; // or .make-col-sm(6)?
   }
   ```

Problem is, from what I've tried I have to `@include "bootstrap"` or insclude specific segments of it, but that causes every CSS that is generated in those files to be exported in each CSS file I generate from my LESS file.

So my question is:

Is there any way to tell LESS where to extract a class to inherit from (A "`@source`" if you will) without having to generate it in the same file?

Comment: Does this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970030/less-extend-not-working help you?

Comment: "each CSS file I generate from my LESS file." Don't folks normally only generate one CSS file from their LESS?

Comment: @crvrebert Well what if I separate LESS files to specific sections or pages of the site?

Comment: @Harry yeah I think that's it. It didn't come up on my search cause the terms are a bit different. I didn't know about the reference keyword and I'll give it a go

Comment: Did that work for you mate?

Comment: Just tried, yep it did. Thanks!